# Join Method with forEach -- best practice?

Tags: join, foreach, delimiter

If this is a bad question, just tell me and I will delete it.  My question is: **Is the attached code the best way to join lines of text with `<hr>` as delimiter?**

I have a table of various listings.  For listings of the same "group" (see array) I want them to be separated by an `<hr>`.  If there is only 1 in the group then I do not want the `<hr>` because it looks bad.  Normally I would use the array.join() method however since I am already using the forEach() I had to come up with this textContent & if/else workaround.

It seems the page loading takes longer than before I implemented the `<hr>` enhancement.  Is this the best way to code it or should I optimize?

```html
<table border="1">
<tr>
  <td id="Group1"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td id="Group2"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td id="Group3"></td>
</tr>
</table>

<script>
var entry = [
["Group1","AAAAAAAAAAAAA"],
["Group2","BBBBBBBBBBBBB"],
["Group2","CCCCCCCCCCCCC"],
["Group3","DDDDDDDDDDDDD"],
["Group3","EEEEEEEEEEEEE"],
["Group3","FFFFFFFFFFFFF"],
]
  
  entry.forEach(
  function myFunction(item, index){
  var x = document.getElementById(item[0]);
  var y = document.getElementById(item[0]).textContent.length;
 
  if(x !== null) {
   if(y < 1) {
    x.innerHTML += item[1];
    }
  else{
  x.innerHTML += '<hr>' + item[1];
  }
  
    
    }
 
  
});

</script>
```